# Decode Cookies Value and save data in databse

Tags: php, laravel-5

1: I am creating a referral system In laravel.SO I am using 
cookies.Problem Is that I am unable to retrieve referral user on blade template.
2: Here is cookie code.
    // Check that there is not already a cookie set and that we have 'ref' in

```
the url
if (! $request->hasCookie('referral') && $request->query('ref') ) {
  // Add a cookie to the response that lasts 5 years (in minutes)
  $response->cookie( 'referral', encrypt( $request->query('ref') ), 525600 );
}
     else {
                if( $request->query('ref') ) {
                    return redirect($request->fullUrl())->withCookie(cookie()->forever('referral', $request->query('ref')));
                }
            }
        return $next($request);
```

2:Here is Crete function code

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $cookie = Cookie::get('referral');
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'referred_by' => $referred_by
    ]);
}
```

Note: I explain one thing is here. this line of code:

```
$referred_by = Cookie::get('referral');
```

is Return this type of output s:2:"21";.

Important issue. My problem is that, how can I retrieve this value on blade temple page.
This is database column value referred_by=s:2:"21"; 
So I need help to retrieve this value for human reading.
Thanks. If anything missing please let me know.

Comment: That appears to be PHP’s `serialize` format, so you can use [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)  to decode it. (Result here would be just the string value `21` then.)

Comment: unserialize@i tried but its not working

Comment: Stop saying “not working”, and give a proper problem description instead. Show what exactly you tried where in the above code, and explain what the result was.

Comment: serialize and unserialize for store any data to database so object or array or any data

Comment: 04FS @ok ..I will update you@ thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well This is work for me.. Thanks

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $cookie = unserialize(Cookie::get('referral'));
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'referred_by' => $referred_by
    ]);
}
```